# Is it possible to submit transactions to Stellar Core directly without Horizon?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, network

Is it possible to submit transactions to Stellar Core directly without Horizon? Or do you need to use Horizon for all interactions with the Stellar network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are HTTP commands that can be issued directly to core.

For example:

```
/tx?blob=Base64
submit a transaction to the network.
```

See https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html

Comment: Incidentally, this is what Horizon uses to send transactions to core